# Invoking Excel macro function with Excel C API

Tags: c++, excel, xll

I'm new to XLL development and have been trying to invoke a registered function as a macro in my XLL. 
I'm trying to get write access to cells adjacent to my calling cell.

The xlSet function looks like it will give me the ability to do that. But it does not look like this function can be called from my Xll function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xlset

From the API, it seems this function needs to be called from a macro. I've tried using the xlUDF function to "trick" excel into thinking I'm running a function as a macro, but haven't had much luck. The xlUDF function gets invoked, but xlSet still fails.

How would I invoke a macro that can call this function ? 
It seems C#/ExcelDna has the equivalent of :

```
object xlApp = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
xlApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, xlApp, new object[]{macroName});
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[It is not permitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-commands-functions-and-states) to call a command from an XLL function for security reasons (especially for writing access..). In your case Excel prevents the calculation thread that runs your Xll function (A) to call your registered command (B) and so "xlset" because otherwise you could, for instance, crash Excel by modifying a cell (via the command) that may be one of the arguments of the function (A).

> xlSet behaves as a Class 3 command-equivalent function; that is, it is
>   available only inside a DLL when the DLL is called from an object,
>   macro, menu, toolbar, shortcut key, or the Run button in the Macro
>   dialog box (accessed from View tab on the ribbon starting in Excel
>   2007, and the Tools menu in earlier versions).
>   [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/xlset)

So if you want to use `xlset`, you need to : 1) call it from a function registered as a macro and 2) you cannot call this macro from your xll, i.e the macro needs to be call by the end user or by the Excel Object Model (VBA, VSTO...).

Regarding ExcelDna, I believe it overcomes the problem by calling the macro (B) from another thread, a COM server, that access the Excel Object Model. In this case the XLL function (A) only delegates the call to a thread that is not restricted. But this may be dangerous.

**Edit :**

I talked with the OP in a chat and it turns out it wanted to expand the cell area via the Excel Object Model. But this is not needed anymore: since fall 2018 , Excel resizes automatically  the xltypeMulti array returned  by the UDF ([dynamic array](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/preview-of-dynamic-arrays-in-excel/ba-p/252944)).

Comment: Thanks Malick! I think I tried performing what you mentioned above by:

Comment: Thanks Malick! I think I tried performing what you mentioned above by:
1. Creating a thread in my Registered XLL function. Eg.
CreateThread(NULL, 0, DisplayGrid, argsArray, 0, NULL)

2. My "DisplayGrid" function would then invoke another function as a macro (I think) using the xlUDF command.
This never worked however and I can't understand why. 
Eg. 
 Excel12(xlfEvaluate, &xNameValue, 1, &xNameText);
 Excel12(xlUDF, &xRes, 2, &xNameValue, &xlRet);
 
3. I never got as far as being able to call xlSet within my "DoDisplay" function, but my intention was to call it from here.

Comment: Would you have any examples on how this can be done?

Comment: No, you need to call your macro function via the Excel Object Model. If you want to stick to C++ you need to do it via COM and so to import the correct library, get a pointer to Excel in xlAutoOpen() and at some point call _ptrExcel->Run("MyMacro").
See also: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/wiki/COM-object-model-notes it is said that even in this case you won't be able to write, see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15837/Accessing-Excel-Spreadsheets-via-C for how to import the library.
The Excel C API is great for functions, for all the rest I would recommend you to look for VSTO.

Comment: Thanks in advance @Malick.
I was able to gt the pointer to the excel instance and evaluate the dispId for the "Run" function (259). However, I got an exception on running the actual macro.


hr = pXlApp->Invoke(dispID, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dps, &result, NULL, NULL);


Would you b able to see what's wrong here? I was hoping this "TestMacro" to be called via the "Run" invocation

Comment: I have created a room : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106591/invoking-excel-macro-function-with-excel-c-api

Comment: Sorry Malick - i dont have enough reputation to join that room. 
But to answer your question, I can call my macro from a cell without problems.

I think this means its registered correctly ?

Comment: you should be able to join the room now

Comment: :( sorry still says I need a reputation of atleast 20

Comment: ok now you have enough reputations, let's continue in the chat room